# What is causing this memory leak when (inner) joining this table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have SQL that in my head, would and should run in under 1 second:

```
SELECT mem.`epid`,
       mem.`model_id`,
       em.`UKM_Make`,
       em.`UKM_Model`,
       em.`UKM_CCM`,
       em.`UKM_Submodel`,
       em.`Year`,
       em.`UKM_StreetName`,
       f.`fit_part_number`
FROM `table_one` AS mem
INNER JOIN `table_two` em ON mem.`epid` = em.`ePID`
INNER JOIN `table_three` f ON `mem`.`model_id` = f.`fit_model_id`
LIMIT 1;
```

When I run in the terminal this SQL executes in 16 seconds. However, if I remove the line:

```
INNER JOIN `table_three` f ON `mem`.`model_id` = f.`fit_model_id`
```

then it executes in 0.03 seconds. Unfortunately for me, I'm not to sure how to debug MYSQL performance issues. This causes my PHP script to run out of memory trying to execute the query.

Here are my table structures:

> table_one

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| epid     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| model_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

> table_two

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ePID           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UKM_Make       | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UKM_Model      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UKM_CCM        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UKM_Submodel   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Year           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UKM_StreetName | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Vehicle Type   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

> table_three

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fit_fitment_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fit_part_number | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fit_model_id    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fit_year_start  | varchar(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fit_year_end    | varchar(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The above is output from `describe $table_name`

Is there anything that I'm obviously missing and if not, how can I try to find out why including `table_three` causes such a slow response time?

**EDIT ONE:**

After the indexing suggestion (used `CREATE INDEX fit_model ON table_three (fit_model_id)`, it performs the query in 0.00 seconds (in MYSQL). Removing the limit, is still running from after doing the suggestion ... so not quite there. Anton's suggestion about using EXPLAIN I used it and got this output:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                  | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mem   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                 |  5587 | Using where                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref  | fit_model     | fit_model | 5       | mastern.mem.model_id |    14 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | em    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                 | 36773 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+----------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT TWO**

I've added a Foreign Key based on suggestions using the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_one`
ADD CONSTRAINT `model_id_fk_tbl_three`
FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`)
REFERENCES `table_three` (`fit_model_id`)
```

MYSQL is still executing the command - there are a lot of rows, so half-expecting this behaviour. With PHP I can break up the query and build my array like that, so I guess that possibly solves the issue - thought is there anything more I can do to try and reduce execution time?

Comment: can you try adding an index for the table 3 , `fit_model_id` and try?

Comment: Spatial Indexes are for geo data, can you try making a unique index by combining it with a primary key or something?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs [this](https://atech.blog/viaduct/mysql-indexes-primer) might be of help.

Comment: If `table_one.model_id` and `table_three.fit_model_id` are in a relation to each other, my best bet would be to use [foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). That adds the index and the relationship to the database.

Comment: @Script47 dankes - was looking forever how to, hate the MYSQL docs layout. Indexed and MYSQL executes in 0.00 sec .. I'll remove limit and see what happens in my PHP script :)

Comment: @KhorneHoly may be worth it .. how does it affect other tables that use `table_three`.`fit_model_id` when used?

Comment: You can use EXPLAIN command before SELECT statement so you can see how many rows are involved, subqueries etc. Let's start with that

Comment: @Anton updated question :)

Comment: Well, you need to ALTER your mem and em tables - there is no correct indexes for such type of search, use FOREIGN KEY (as @KhorneHoly suggests)

Comment: @Anton how will that affect other tables that use those fields?

Comment: It just cross-reference to another table. Use it:) But check manual of course - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @Anton ah ok, so adding a FK won't affect other tables directly? Just the ones mentioned in the FK?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs No, enforcing referential integrity via FK is that database engine is optimized to do. Problems can arise when you use too many indexes - but that is another part of story

Comment: @Anton ah I see. ok cool it's been added, but seems a change hasn't been made, still just hangs on the query :/ it is 36K rows or so .. how long should I be expecting to wait?

Comment: Yep, altering big tables with adding indexes can take a lot of time. I assume you have updated MAX_EXECUTION_TIME var. And don't forget to run OPTIMIZE TABLE query from time to time in case of massive insert/update/delete operations

Comment: @Anton I've so far just increased the limit in 1000s increment - allow the search to happen, index the results, then next use it just has to index whatever isn't indexed - seems to be getting there, on 40k at the momento, added a time taken function for the script just to see how long it takes - if you'd like to add an answer about indexes, foreign keys and optimize table I can accept :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs done. My thumb also for KhorneHoly who mentioned about FK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on everyone's comments etc. I managed to perform a few things that made my query run a hell of a lot quicker and not crash my script.

1) Indexes

I created an index on my `table_three` for the field `fit_model_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX fit_model ON `table_three` (`fit_model_id`);
```

This made my LIMIT 1 query go from 16 seconds to 0.03 seconds execution time (in MYSQL CLI).

However, 100 rows or so would still take a lot longer than I thought.

2) Foreign Keys

I created a foreign key that linked `table_one`.`model_id` = `table_three`.`fit_model_id` using the below query:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_one`
ADD CONSTRAINT `model_id_fk_tbl_three`
FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`)
REFERENCES `table_three` (`fit_model_id`)
```

This definitely helped, but still felt like more could be done.

3) OPTIMIZE TABLE

I then used `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on these tables:

- table_one
- table_three

This then made my script work and my query fast as ever. However, the issue I had was a large data set, so I let, the query run in MYSQL CLI whilst increasing the LIMIT by 1000 each script run time to help the indexing process, got all the way to 30K rows before it started crashing.

CLI took 31 minutes and 8 seconds to complete. So I did this:

> 31 x 60 = 1860
>
> 1860 + 8 = 1868
>
> 1868 / 448476 = 0.0042

So each row took 0.0042 seconds to complete - which is fast enough in my eyes.

Thanks to everyone for commenting and helping me debug and fix the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments correct answer is as follows:

1. In case of long execution of select statement add EXPLAIN statement before SELECT
2. Check whether `possible_keys` are empty in subqueries for specific tables.
3. Add [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)s for tables found in step 2. In case of vast table it's recommended to adjust MAX_EXECUTION_TIME variable (can be done for single query)
4. In case of massive insert/update/delete operations OPTIMIZE TABLE can adjust performance also.